# Python Using pyplot slider with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, slider, matplotlib-widget

I am quite new to Python, so please excuse if this is a stupid beginner's error. However I am struggling with it for quite some time.
I want to create a figure with n x m subplots, each subplot being np.array of shape [1024,264,264]. As I am looking for differences occuring in the stack along the 0-dimension I want to use a slider to explore all stacks in my figure simultaneously. 
The slider instance works nicely for a figure with one subplot but I can't bring them all to work.
That's the code I am using:

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import glob
import h5py
#Define the xy size of the mapped array
xsize=3
ysize=3

lengthh5=9
readlist=[]
for i in range (0,lengthh5):
    npraw=np.random.rand(200,50,50)
    readlist.append (npraw)

''' Slider visualization'''
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
fig=plt.figure()
for k in range (0,lengthh5):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(xsize,ysize,k)        
    frame = 10
    l = ax.imshow(readlist[k][frame,:,:]) 
    plt.axis('off')
           sframe = Slider(fig.add_subplot(50,1,50), 'Frame', 0, len(readlist[0])-1, valinit=0)
    def update(val):
        frame = np.around(sframe.val)
        l.set_data(readlist[k][frame,:,:])


sframe.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

For this particular case I stripped it down to a 3x3 array for my figure and just create randmom (smaller) arrays.
The slider is interestinly only operable on the second last subplot. However I have no real idea how to link it to all subplots simulatenously. Perhaps someone has an idea how to do this.
Thanks a lot in advance,

Tilman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store each `imshow` AxesImage in a list and inside update, loop over all of them and update each based on the slider,

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

import glob
import h5py
#Define the xy size of the mapped array
xsize=3
ysize=3

lengthh5=9
readlist=[]
for i in range (0,lengthh5):
    npraw=np.random.rand(200,50,50)
    readlist.append (npraw)

fig=plt.figure()
ls = []
for k in range (0,lengthh5):
    ax=fig.add_subplot(xsize,ysize,k)        
    frame = 10
    l = ax.imshow(readlist[k][frame,:,:]) 
    ls.append(l)
    plt.axis('off')

sframe = Slider(fig.add_subplot(50,1,50), 'Frame', 
                0, len(readlist[0])-1, valinit=0)

def update(val):
    frame = np.around(sframe.val)
    for k, l in enumerate(ls):
        l.set_data(readlist[k][frame,:,:])

sframe.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the swift help

Comment: Sorry for prematurely accepting the answer. I played around with actual data that gave more "features" than random data. There it appears that now I am inserting the 8th image of my array to all the 9 images when I move the slider. The image is changing but it's just the eigths. I guess it's related to the k in the l for loop in the update but I don't have a solution right now.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed the `k` index on the readlist which should change with axis number too (changed above using enumerate).

Comment: @EdSmith You added `k` sliders, if you just change `sframe = Slider(fig.add_subplot(50,1+k,50),...` you would notice that, so at the end you are playing with the last plotted slider. If you just remove the intend before that line it works fine.

Comment: @philippos, intend? I assume you mean indent, good spot, I've adjusted the example.

Comment: @EdSmith You are right! it's `indent`. sorry my mistyping :)